# Have I made a mistake on using sscanf function?

Tags: c

I am trying to get datas by sscanf from hoge.txt.(see below)

But I have got curious results.

I can not understand why this happens.

Please help.

I compiled&linked by Borland C/C++ 5.5.1 for Win32 - if that help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;
    char buf[100];
    char name1[100];
    char name2[100];
    int distance1;
    int distance2;

    /* file open */
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp == NULL){
       return -1;
    }

    /* get a line */
    fgets(buf,100,fp);

    /* change \n to \0 */
    strtok(buf,"\n");

    /* get values from buf */
    sscanf(buf,"%s,%d; %s,%d;",name1,&distance1,name2,&distance2);

    /* for tests */
    printf("%s\n",name1);
    printf("%s\n",name2);
    printf("%d\n",distance1);
    printf("%d\n",distance2);

    return 0;
}
```

【hoge.txt】※just a line

Ramytdb,2683; Voclqmb,5236;

【result】

Ramytdb,2683;
ﾜlﾚwD
1
256

Comment: The first _mistake_, not to check the return value of `sscanf()`

Comment: ... which tells you the number of arguments successfully parsed.

Comment: ..and also, try to use the return value of `strtok()`.

Comment: @Gopi its to set the newline to null char if it is present; a not-very-common way to do so. Its rather pointless in this case, to be sure.

Comment: @Gopi "I can know the position where there is \n" and you know this... how? `fgets` will include it if encountered within N-1 chars, but will *not* include it otherwise (i.e. a partial line). The OP's `strtok` is a no-harm way of setting it to 0 if found, and a no-op if not.

Comment: @WhozCraig  Does `strtok(buf,"\n");` simply return `NULL` and not change `buf` when `buf == "\n"`?  (of course that would not make a difference in OP's case)

Comment: @chux if presented only with `"\n"`, the OP's code should fail to strip the delimiter entirely, and yes, return NULL. [see it live](http://ideone.com/jRHpNP).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use

```
sscanf(buf,"%[^,],%d; %[^,],%d;",name1,&distance1,name2,&distance2);
```

instead of

```
sscanf(buf,"%s,%d; %s,%d;",name1,&distance1,name2,&distance2);
```

Your code failed because `%s` doesn't stop scanning when it sees `,`. It stops scanning when it encounters a `\n` or a space. In your case,it scans `Ramytdb,2683;` and stops as the next character is a space. This causes things to mess up.

You can also provide more safety by limiting the amount of characters to read by using

```
sscanf(buf,"%99[^,],%d; %99[^,],%d;",name1,&distance1,name2,&distance2);
```

Note that you need one space for the `\0` character at the end of the string and that is why I've used 99 instead of 100.

You can further improve it by checking the result of `sscanf` .[`sscanf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) returns the number of variables filled. So check if it returns 4 by using

```
if(sscanf(buf,"%[^,],%d; %[^,],%d;",name1,&distance1,name2,&distance2)==4)
  //sscanf was successful
else
  //sscanf was not successful
```

You can also add a `%*c` at the end of the `sscanf`. This would read a character and discard it. If you have a `\n` character at the end of the line in the file,this can be useful.

Comment: Suggest `char dummy; sscanf(buf,"%99[^,],%d; %99[^,],%d;%c, ..., &dummy) == 4"` and check result.  Note no need for the last `;` unless further test is done like the %c

Comment: @chux , The `sscanf` in your comment will return 5 when successful,right?

Comment: Only 4 is correct. 5 meant something extra occurred after the `;`.  There are a number of approach to insure the `;` occurred and nothing else.  This is just a quick idea.  %n after the final `;` is another approach.

Comment: @chux ,`%n` scans a `\n` and discards it right? Or does it move the file pointer to the next line?

Comment: `int n; sscanf(bif, ...%n..., &n)` simply saves the offset in `buf` where scanning was at that point.  Example `int n=0; sscanf(buf,"%[^,],%d; %[^,],%d; %n", ..., &n); if (n && buf[n] == '\0') Success()`.

Comment: @chux , So it doesn't scan anything from the file and the file pointer stays where it is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67896/discussion-between-chux-and-cool-guy).

Comment: I have understood what is wrong - a way of format.As following your answer , my problem has solved. Sorry to be a late response and thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the manual page the conversion

> s
>
> Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters; the next pointer
>   must be a pointer to character array that is long enough to hold the
>   input sequence and the terminating null byte ('\0'), which is added
>   automatically. The input string stops at white space or at the maximum
>   field width, whichever occurs first.

So the first %s will read as many characters as it can that are non-white space. That would include the comma. Therefore by checking the return value you will notice this.

You will need to use another conversion - perhaps ']'? A look on the web page http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf will help you decide